# Tangent line of $(f^{-1})^{'}$, where $f(x) = \int_{0}^{x} 1 + \frac{\sin(\sin(t))}{t} dt$

Tags: calculus, analysis

As the title says, how could I find the tangent line at $x_0 = 0$ of $(f^{-1})^{'}$, where $f(x) = \int_{0}^{x} 1 + \frac{\sin(\sin(t))}{t} dt$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Can you find $f(0)$ and $f'(0)$ ?

Comment: I already know $f^{-1}$ exists, given that the integral is always positive, but i'm struggling to apply the inverse function theorem, since it requires a definition of $f^{-1}$ for $(f^{-1})^{'} $

Comment: Okay, notice that you don't actually require the entire function $f^{-1}(x)$. It is sufficient if you know the value $f^{-1}(0)$

Comment: @rsadhvika Oh, is it possible that it cannot be found? I was so blindly concentrated on finding $f^{-1}$ that I didn't notice that $f^{'} (0)$ is undefined...

Comment: Ahh I too have just noticed that $t$ in the bottom. Must be a mistake from your teacher. I feel your teacher will be more happy if you show some work instead of simply saying $f^{'}(0)$ is undefined..

Comment: Why isn't $f'(0) = 1$?

Comment: Undefined, since you can't divide by 0. You could take the limit, in which case you would get that $\lim_{x \to 0} f^{'} (x) = 2$, given that $\sin x \approx x$ (Taylor polynomial arround 0), and thus $\sin ( \sin(x) ) \approx \sin(x)$, finally getting that the limit of the non constant part tends to 1.

Comment: sorry, 2. Not undefined though

Comment: @CalvinKhor Not actually. The derivative, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus would be $f^{'} (x) = 1 + \frac{ \sin( \sin x ) )}{x}$. Thus, $f^{'} (0)$ is undefined.

Comment: have you read my answer? Your objections are not a problem because: 1. depending on your formulation for the FTC, it won't tell you the value of the derivative at the end points anyway; 2. Of course the previous point is easy to work around by considering instead the integral from say $-1$ to $x$ instead. Then the issue is: is the integrand continuous at 0, so that FTC can be applied? The integrand can be modified at 0 to be a continuous function, so in fact the answer is yes.  But this is a bit fiddly and it is easy to just directly compute the limit as I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch. 
$$ \int_0^x 1 + \frac{\sin\sin t}{t} dt = x + \int_0^x \underbrace{\frac{\sin\sin t}{\sin t}}_{\approx 1}\underbrace{\frac{\sin t}{t} }_{\approx 1}dt $$
for $|x|\ll 1$, which is also valid for $x<0$. So directly from the limit definition,
$$\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = 1 + \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \frac{\sin\sin t}{t} dt \xrightarrow[x\to0]{} 2$$

Thus since $f(x_0) = 0$, the gradient of the tangent line at $x_0$ is
$$ (f^{-1})'(0) = \frac1{f'(f^{-1}(0))} = \frac{1}{f'(0)} = \frac{1}{2}$$